# blazor change checkbox to disabled when clicked

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have a checkbox inside a foreach like that:

```
    @foreach (var m in message)
{
    <div>
        Mark as read:
  
        <input type="checkbox" value="@m.Idmsg" id="@m.Idmsg" @onclick="@(() => CheckedReadMsg(Items, m.Idmsg, UserName))" disabled="@CBDisabled" />

    </div>

}
```

My Razor page is like that:

```
     async Task CheckedReadMsg(MultiSelectList e, int IDMSG2, string UserConfirming)
    {
        await repoRelationships.ConfirmCheckBox(IDMSG2, UserConfirming);
        CBDisabled = true;
    }
```

I saw several examples there on how to fix it but when fire `CBDisabled` it disable all checkbox.
Some idea guys?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different solution demo'd in a standalone Razor Page.  You will need an `Ack` property in you `message` class.  There are two slightly different formatted versions, one where the whole message is clickable, the other where only the checkbox is clickable.  I've added a bit of colour formatting.

```
@page "/checkbox"
<h3>CheckBoxes 1</h3>
@foreach (var message in messages)
{
    <div class="p-2 m-2 @GetColor(message.Ack)" style="cursor:pointer" @onclick="() => SetRead(message.MessageID)">
        <input type="checkbox" value=@message.Text disabled=@message.Ack checked=@message.Ack />
        <span class="px-3">@message.Text</span>
    </div>
}
<h3>CheckBoxes 2</h3>
@foreach (var message in messages)
{
    <div class="p-2 m-2 @GetColor(message.Ack)">
        <input type="checkbox" value=@message.Text disabled=@message.Ack checked=@message.Ack @onclick="() => SetRead(message.MessageID)" />
        <span class="px-3">@message.Text</span>
    </div>
}

@code {

    class Message
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public Guid MessageID { get; } = Guid.NewGuid();
        public bool Ack { get; set; }
    }

    List<Message> messages = new List<Message>
{
          new Message { Text = "Message 1" }, 
          new Message { Text="Message 2" }, 
          new Message { Text="Message 3" }
    };

    string GetColor(bool ack)
        => ack ? "bg-success" : "bg-light";

    private void SetRead(Guid id)
    {
        var message = messages.FirstOrDefault(item => item.MessageID.Equals(id));
        message.Ack = true;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that single bool `CBDisabled` is controlling the `disabled` attribute for all the checkboxes. To fix this so that each checkbox can be disabled independently, you'll need one bool for each checkbox. There are many ways you could do this, but here is how to use a dictionary to track the disabled states for each checkbox:

```cs
public class MyClass
{
  private readonly Dictionary<string, bool> disabledStates = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

  protected override void OnInitialized()
  {
    // once `message` exists, populate the dictionary with the needed key/value pairs
    foreach (var m in message)
    {
      // we assume that `m.Idmsg` is unique across all "messages"
      disabledStates.Add(m.Idmsg, false);
    }
  }

  async Task CheckedReadMsg(MultiSelectList e, int IDMSG2, string UserConfirming)
  {
    await repoRelationships.ConfirmCheckBox(IDMSG2, UserConfirming);
    // disable the clicked checkbox only
    disabledStates[m.Idmsg] = true;
  }
}
```

```html
@foreach (var m in message)
{
    <div>
        Mark as read:
  
        <input type="checkbox" value="@m.Idmsg" id="@m.Idmsg" @onclick="@(() => CheckedReadMsg(Items, m.Idmsg, UserName))" disabled="@disabledStates[m.Idmsg]" />

    </div>

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not containing state for each row. You appear to be using one value `CBDisabled` for all rows. All the other answers here are right. The easiest way to fix this is to break the contents of your `@foreach` loop into another component.

```
@foreach (var m in message)
{
    <MarkAsRead Message="@m"/>
}
```

`MarkAsRead.razor`

```
<div>
    Mark as read:

    <input type="checkbox" value="@Message.Idmsg" id="@Message.Idmsg" @onclick="@(() => CheckedReadMsg(Items, Message.Idmsg, UserName))" disabled="@CBDisabled" />

</div>

@code {
    ...

    bool CBDisabled = false;

    [Parameter]
    public SomeClass Message { get; set; }

    async Task CheckedReadMsg(MultiSelectList e, int IDMSG2, string UserConfirming)
    {
        await repoRelationships.ConfirmCheckBox(IDMSG2, UserConfirming);
        CBDisabled = true;
    }
}
```